# ftp:// web page in FF and Chrome does not load file:// script

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, ftp, file-uri

I'm building a web page which I can only access by ftp:

ftp://192.168.0.1.cutthis/mypage.html

This url opens the page in the browser as I would have used http protocol.

The page contains a dynamic GUI. To make its development easier, I have moved all the javascript to a machine (192.168.0.2) I have access to, so I can edit it more quickqly. In the html source code of mypage.html, the script line is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file://///192.168.0.2/myscript.js"></script>
```

FF and Chrome load the script (Firebug confirms this) but don't run it. Only IE run it.

How can I force FF and/or Chrome to run the script? Or how can I solve the problem overwise?

Comment: What's up with the five slashes in `file://///`?

Comment: Do you actually have a file in your root directory called `192.168.0.2`?

Comment: @arxanas: less backslashes do not work

Comment: @gorlok: Not sure what you are asking to me. I'm forced to useda machine whose ip is different from 192.168.0.1

Comment: @apsillers. I have a file called myscript.js

Comment: I repeat: FF and Chrome *LOAD* the script into the DOM!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cross-protocol scripting?

**Method 1:**

For Chrome try extension: LocalLinks

For FF try extensions: LocalLink, Local Filesystem Links, IE Tab

**Method 2:**

run Chrome with --allow-file-access-from-files flag
or may be try other flag which disables cross-site scripting (waring: this is dangerous)

configure Security Policy in FF (create special policy for your site - read here: [Links_to_local_pages_don't_work](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Links_to_local_pages_don%27t_work), [Security_Policies](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Security_Policies))

But, I'm still not sure if all of this helps. FTP: URL is a special case

Answer (score 0):

MDN says of the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript):

> The same origin policy prevents a document or script loaded from one origin from getting or setting properties of a document from another origin.

`myscript.js` is from the origin `file:////192.168.0.2/` but it is being loaded into a page with the origin `ftp://192.168.0.1.cutthis`. My guess is that the cross-domain script cannot perform the manipulation you expect it to do because it is loaded from a different origin.

The solution would be to host both the script and the page on the same origin (i.e., also serve the HTML page over `file://`, or even better, serve them both on a local HTTP server).

Comment: I doubt. There is a plethora of web pages which load scripts from other domain (Jquery, for example). Here the difference is only in protocol. Does the rule you cite discuss explicitely about different protocols?

Comment: It's also possible that this is a special case of `file:` same-origin strictness. Are you seeing any errors at all in the console?